# Difference of two fourth powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is well known that an integer can be expressed as the difference of two integer squares iff it is odd or a multiple of $4$.

Is there a similar characterization of the integers that can be expressed as the difference of two fourth powers?

Comment: Motivated by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371933/theory-of-equations-number-of-positive-integral-solutions.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A152044.

Comment: The finite difference method says that you get $4aq^3+6a^2q^2+4a^3q+a^4$, which says that there is minimally a factor of $8$ for the even differences, and the whole number space is quite restricted compared to the difference of squares...